# Can I connect my water heater to a faucet with no vent connection?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

I had two instant hot water faucets in my house:

1. In the kitchen with a nice faucet, where everyone used it, but the tank now leaks and needs to be replaced. This tank (which now leaks), has two connections on it - water in and water out - and no vent.
2. In the basement with an ugly faucet (model H770-22) where no one uses it. This tank has an additional "vent" connection.

I'd like to take the tank from the basement and use it to replace the leaky tank in the kitchen, but I'd like to keep the nice faucet that's already in the kitchen that doesn't have a connection for venting. Am I able to do it or is the basement tank (yes venting connection) incompatible with the kitchen faucet (no venting connection)?

Here's the one that leaks:

[image]

Here's the one I want to replace it with:

[image]

Diagram for the second one:

[image]

Comment: Where does the vent connection go?

Comment: Brand and models of the water heaters? Pics of the installations? You can [edit] those into your question to help us help you...

Comment: Added the pictures of the tanks

Comment: In your diagram the vent seems to be coming from the expansion chamber. Look at the installation diagrams for the new one and see if it has something similar.

Comment: The "new" tank has a vent, the old one doesn't and nor does that old faucet that I want to keep.